# Angularjs apps, modules, directives, and organization

Tags: angularjs

I have an angularjs application, it has three separate use-cases, one for users to come in and submit requests, another for agents to view and run-down requests and a third to administer the application (users (reset passwords, disable, change details), change values the forms can have, etc).

I've started working on the administrator view and have been using one app (or is it a module?) with different routes with templates (I'd like to think of them as views) and controllers for each of the different components the admins can administer.

I didn't want to get too far ahead of myself before a reality check: Is this an appropriate use of modules, for me to basically have 1 module for each of my entry points?  If I have a directive, say a user picker, that I use in the admin module, how can I reuse it in my other modules?

Comment: `angular.module('adminApp', ['userApp']);`

Comment: So if I need one directive from another module, I just inject the entire module?  Should I make modules that only have directives?

Comment: Yes. AngularJS was made to be modular. Splitting up your things into tiny little modules is -exactly- the way the team wants you to use angular. This is great for re-use of code too. If you need your user picker for a new app that you develop next year, you can just grab the module and put it into your new app.

Comment: So you're saying I should make a separate module for each thing I want to have a controller for in my admin view?  And, just to be clear, I can make something like angular.module('userPicker').directive(...) and inject that and use it and should pick it up and work properly?

Comment: It's hard to decide which components should have their own module. I suppose you need to ask yourself, "Is this something which I can use in more software I make in future?" - If the answer is yes, then make it a module. A good example of this are the many modules available from the Angular-UI team. -- As for injecting, yes just add it to the list of modules when you define your user or admin modules, like this: `angular.module('userApp', ['userPicker']);` Now the userPicker module (with all its directives, services, filters, etc) will be available for injection into your userApp module.